# Why was my spam flag declined?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, spam

I am extremely confused on how my flag for spam went denied. I can't show the question because it has *already* been deleted, but I think you can tell by the title alone this question wasn't even a question, but rather a post of random letters and code. [image]

I'm pretty sure there were three comments on the post itself mentioning the word "spam". The post consisted of three random fields of java with the text "ddddddddddddddddddd..." (for a long time) at the end. Can someone explain to me why my flag would've been denied in the clear case that it was spam?

The link for users with over 10k rep https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291500/expandablelkisat-expandablelkisat-expandablelkisat-expandablelkisat

Comment: You can still give us the link to the question here; people with 10k can still see such posts.

Comment: Added the link for you

Comment: Had an exact question on a different flag? Glad this was answered before on meta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep spam flags for *commercial messages we didn't ask for*. These posts are fed into the automatic spam detection system, so moderators are strict on what goes in.

For nonsense answer posts use the *Not An Answer* or *Very Low Quality* flags:

> [image: flagging options for answers]

If it was a question, there is a *Very Low Quality* option there too:

> [image: flagging options for questions]

but downvoting and closing as *Unclear what you are asking* is perfectly valid too.

From the title from your screenshot it looks as if *Very Low Quality* fits best there; absolute gibberish cannot be salvaged through editing.

Comment: Oh. Being new to Stack Overflow, I didn't read the description of the flag before using it. I mistakenly assumed spam fell into the category of useless crap. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Don't these messages count as abusive, though?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Perhaps, if there is a pattern of trolling you can flag for moderator attention. That doesn't make them spam, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak No, both spam and "offensive, abusive, or hate speech" flags feed into separate queues, so they have very specific meanings. Use a custom flag if you see repeated keyboard pounding posts from one account.

Comment: As an addition: Spam flags can have a severe impact on a user's account; there's a pretty severe reputation penalty involved, and repeated spam flags can cause suspension (or even banning) of a user's account. It's the reason that "spam" has a very specific definition here.

Comment: @KenWhite users that keep posting random collections of characters repeatedly deserve a 100 rep penalty.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I have actually heard from a moderator that these messages count as offensive. Moreover, the privacy policy does define them as spam.